# Pick random record from Firebase with AngularFire

Tags: database, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Is there any way to get random record from firebase like this:

```
{
  "-JbmopNnshefBT2nS2S7" : {
    "dislike" : 0,
    "like" : 0,
    "post" : "First post."
  },
  "-JbmoudijnJjDBSXNQ8_" : {
    "dislike" : 0,
    "like" : 0,
    "post" : "Second post."
  }
}
```

I used this code to solve the problem, but it download all records, so if DB would be bigger, my app will work very slow:

HTML code:

```
    <div ng-controller="RandomCtrl">{{RandomPost.post}}</div>
```

JS code:

```
var app=angular.module('App', ['firebase']);

app.controller('RandomCtrl', function($scope, $firebase){
    var ref = new Firebase("https://ind.firebaseio.com/");
    var sync=$firebase(ref);

    $scope.messages = sync.$asArray();

    $scope.GetRandomPost=function(){
        return $scope.RandomPost=$scope.messages[Math.floor(Math.random()*$scope.messages.length)];
    };

    $scope.GetRandomPost();    

});
```

Comment: you can use increment as a key and then simply randomly pick one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use startAt with your own incremental index. For example, suppose you have index (0 to n) in your records.

Do this query: orderByChild("index").startAt(rint).limitToFirst(1);

See the code snippit:

```
var rint = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10)) // you have 10 records
var query = ref.orderByChild("index").startAt(rint).limitToFirst(1);

var results = $firebaseArray(query);
results.$loaded(
  function(x) {
    // let's get one
    $scope.oneResult = x[0];
  }, function(error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with an object that contains all keys to solve the issue with large DBs, regarding picking up a random key I think you are good the way you are doing it.

Another way to do I guess is using incremental keys as @lombausch said, then you can use a combination of key() method to get the last key added and then get a random based on the min, max values.

Here is the anti-pattern to save incremental/numeric keys:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-push

key() method reference:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/key.html

Comment: Thank you and @lombausch for answers! But i can't understand, how i can  store data using incremental keys, because Firebase makes unique keys instead. For example, i want to add data like this: {"name":"Alex",city:"LA"} and {"name":"Sam","city":"Berlin"}. After sending i want to get DB like this: {1:{"name":"Alex",city:"LA"},2:{"name":"Sam","city":"Berlin"}}. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Did you check my first link using set() you can specify the key you want (an incremental value) but like mentioned in the docs you may or not run into some issues with concurrency/simultaneous writings.