# How to randomize data in ng-repeat in firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I had some idea in mind, I want to create firebase data about quotes look like this

```
quotes:{
    ObjectId:{
         title: "When there's a will there's a way"
       },
    ObjectId:{
         title: "When there's a will there's a way"
       }
}
```

What I want to do is, I want to show it but randomly fading. 
If we use ng-repeat it would likely to show all of them.
Any suggestion for what library should I use ?
thank you so much for your help.

Comment: See this question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178393/pick-random-record-from-firebase-with-angularfire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a 2ed array. Fill the 2ed array with random values of the 1st array, and use bind your page/ng-repeat on the 2ed array :)

Comment: Thank you, any idea how would we change the data every second ?

Comment: At the end of your 'Refresh' function, call 'setTimeout(Refresh, 1000)' so your 'Refresh' function will be called every 1s.